# how to put this login system on my website with html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, authentication

I tried to search on several google sites, but I don't know what this window is called, I referred to it in the search as a popup.

I want to put this login system on my html site:

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Unfortunatly your  question does not meet the SO guidelines. So is a plattform for developers that have a specific coding issue. Means that they already have some code but are stuck and need debugging help. It is expected that you already tried to solve the issue on your own and have done some research efford. Using google is a good start but does not exclude that you should start an attempt to solve it on your own. If you did, please add a minimal reproduciable code snippet and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi Wellinton. With html you can create the structure (flow) of the form with the input fields, button, etc. With css you can give this a design, for example colors, dimensions, etc. The login data from the user has to be validated. This is possible with php or asp.net.

Comment: @bron - Neither HTML or CSS is involved when using basic auth (which it looks like their asking about). The server returns a header telling the browser to show the login prompt. The browser then sends the data to the server. There's no form or HTML involved.

Comment: @Magnus. I did use the term "validation" meaning the same as authentication. And ofcouse, php and asp.net are server-related lanuages. We said the same in other words.

Answer (score 1):

That looks the website has an [apache .htpasswd file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04) set up, which makes the server reqire basic authentication before it even sends you the html.  If youre using Nginx, [it also supports using .htpasswd files.](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/)

### Requirements

- htpasswd utility, part of the `apache2-utils` package on Debian or `httpd-tools` on RHEL

### Creating the file

```sh
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd [desired_username]
```

You will be asked to enter a password for the user.
If you want to add more than 1 user, run the command again without the `-c` and provide a different username and password.

### Configuring Apache to use the .htpasswd file

Edit the apache `default-ssl.conf` (usually at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`) file to tell it which directories to restrict with your user/password.
The root directory (entire website) is usually `/var/www/html`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Content"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### Restart the server

```sh
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: You don't need to touch the web server if you don't want to. You can implement basic auth using PHP directly as well: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php